# two specific rank should be shown on the page

Tags: sql

this is how my sql need to find out about the use of rank 1 and from 3 up of must for any content shown on the page.

I have done this:

```
SELECT id FROM brugere WHERE Id = @id and rank >= 3 and rank = 1
```

Trouble is that it will only show rank 3 and up content rather on the side but from 1 rank will not display content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT id FROM brugere WHERE Id = @id and (rank >= 3 OR rank = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! :) ha a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome. Another option might be to use ... AND rank <> 2.

Comment: What its the best for sql? or for me?